# ASP.NET Saving Customer's Shipping/Billing Addresses

Tags: asp.net

I'm looking for the simplest solution to this situation:

I have a pre existing web store with a shopping cart using .NET (vbscript)

I customize what products my customer's see based on the subdomain they use to come to my site (customer.mysite.com)

What my customer's are requesting is, instead of typing in their billing/shipping addresses each time, that they have a selection to choose from from previous addresses they have used.

How can I accomplish this, keeping in mind that they don't log in, they simply use the subdomain to come in to my site and place orders without a user/pass.

The simpler (easier to implement) solution, the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just show all the addresses for that subdomain, but, due to some privacy concerns, I would wait until they type in a street address, then show them the addresses for that.

Otherwise, everyone on that subdomain will see the address of everyone else on that subdomain.

If they don't care, then just show all the addresses for that subdomain.

Or, give them an option to login and order, and then when they do that, then you can show them all their addresses they shipped do when they are logged in.

The last one is the preferred one, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If they don't login then I assume you don't have them create an account either.  Thus the server won't be able to identify them.  In this case I think you are left with using client cookies.  Just make sure you don't store sensitive data in them (like credit card).

Comment: Yeah they don't create accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I would place a cookie on the users computer with the address information in it attached to the subdomain. The down side to this is that you should not put sensitive information inside cookies but depending on the nature of your business this may not be a problem for you.

Comment: I'm just placing addresses, so is that considered sensitive data?

Comment: Yes.  If you must use a cookie, encrypt it.

Comment: @Sev - If it is unencrypted in a cookie someone can read it. Do you want people getting your addresses?